# How to convert a NSData to pdf in iPhone sdk?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, pdf, nsdata

Am converting a webpage as a pdf file. I did the following,

```
NSString *string=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.pdf",[chapersArray objectAtIndex:pageIndex]];
[controller1 addAttachmentData:pdfData mimeType:@"application/pdf" fileName:string];
[self presentModalViewController:controller1 animated:YES];
[controller1 release];
```

Now how can i convert my NSData into pdf and save in my application memory? Kindly help me with sample codes or suggestions. Thanks all.

Comment: Where does pdfData come from?

Comment: Sorry friend i confused you. I want to convert NSData into pdf and store in my application memory.

Comment: What the hell does "store in my application memory" mean? An NSData object is already in memory. Also "convert to PDF" doesn't mean anything without explaining what format you're converting from.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Am assuming you have your pdf in documents directory here. You can change it to where ever it actually is. Try this -

```
//to convert pdf to NSData
NSString *pdfPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.pdf"]; 
NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:pdfPath];
```

Essentially using [CGPDFDocumentCreateWithProvider](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGPDFDocument/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL) you can convert `NSData` to pdf,

```
//to convert NSData to pdf
NSData *data               = //some nsdata
CFDataRef myPDFData        = (CFDataRef)data;
CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData(myPDFData);
CGPDFDocumentRef pdf       = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithProvider(provider);
```

Don't forget to `CFRelease` all unused data after you are done.

Comment: Sorry friend i confused you. I want to convert NSData into pdf and store in my application memory.

Comment: @Srikar Appal Hello, how to store this pdf to a file.

Comment: @EaswaramoorthyKanagaraj this should do it `[myFile writeToFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath], @"yourfilename.pdf"] atomically:YES];`

Comment: @SrikarAppal What is myFile here, Is it myData in first code snippet? Or something else in the second snippet? Please kindly clarify this and also the method you are talking about.

Comment: @SrikarAppal, I tried to save the file using "writeToFile:" but it doesn't open the file. Any help how to save the above CGPDFDocumentRef object to pdf file

Answer (score 3):

I got this is in a simple method as follows,

```
-(IBAction)saveasPDF:(id)sender{
     NSString *string=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.pdf",[chapersArray objectAtIndex:pageIndex]];
     [controller1 addAttachmentData:pdfData mimeType:@"application/pdf" fileName:string];
     [self presentModalViewController:controller1 animated:YES];
     [pdfData writeToFile:[self getDBPathPDf:string] atomically:YES];
        }

-(NSString *) getDBPathPDf:(NSString *)PdfName {
   NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory , NSUserDomainMask, YES);
   NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    return [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:PdfName];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this solution:

```
- (void)saveDataToPDF:(NSData *)pdfDocumentData
{
    //Create the pdf document reference
    CGDataProviderRef dataProvider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData((CFDataRef)pdfDocumentData);
    CGPDFDocumentRef document = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithProvider(dataProvider);

    //Create the pdf context
    CGPDFPageRef page = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(document, 1); //Pages are numbered starting at 1
    CGRect pageRect = CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(page, kCGPDFMediaBox);
    CFMutableDataRef mutableData = CFDataCreateMutable(NULL, 0);

    //NSLog(@"w:%2.2f, h:%2.2f",pageRect.size.width, pageRect.size.height);
    CGDataConsumerRef dataConsumer = CGDataConsumerCreateWithCFData(mutableData);
    CGContextRef pdfContext = CGPDFContextCreate(dataConsumer, &pageRect, NULL);


    if (CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages(document) > 0)
    {
        //Draw the page onto the new context
        //page = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(document, 1); //Pages are numbered starting at 1

        CGPDFContextBeginPage(pdfContext, NULL);
        CGContextDrawPDFPage(pdfContext, page);
        CGPDFContextEndPage(pdfContext);
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Failed to create the document");
    }

    CGContextRelease(pdfContext); //Release before writing data to disk.

    //Write to disk
    [(__bridge NSData *)mutableData writeToFile:@"/Users/David/Desktop/test.pdf" atomically:YES];

    //Clean up
    CGDataProviderRelease(dataProvider); //Release the data provider
    CGDataConsumerRelease(dataConsumer);
    CGPDFDocumentRelease(document);
    CFRelease(mutableData);
}
```