# Save NSData as PDF file

Tags: ios

I am trying to save some NSData in pdf format. The NSData is from a downloaded pdf. This is how I tried to do it:

```
NSData* data = [DKStoreManager loadFileWithName:_FileName forFolderNumber:[_FolderNumber intValue] forUser:userID andType:_FolderType];
    NSDictionary *myDictionary = (NSDictionary*) [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];

    NSData* dataFile;

        NSMutableDictionary* dict = [myDictionary objectForKey:@"MultiFileOtherFile2"];
        dataFile = [dict objectForKey:@"FileData"];


    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *pdfPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"mLocalFileName.pdf"];
    [dataFile writeToFile:pdfPath atomically:YES];

    NSString *phrase = nil; // Document password (for unlocking most encrypted PDF files)
    ReaderDocument *document = [ReaderDocument withDocumentFilePath:pdfPath password:phrase];
```

This doesn't work. The only thing that works is:

```
NSArray *pdfs = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathsForResourcesOfType:@"pdf" inDirectory:nil];
 NSString *filePath = [pdfs lastObject]; assert(filePath != nil); // Path to last PDF file
ReaderDocument *document = [ReaderDocument withDocumentFilePath:filePath password:phrase];
```

...with a pdf added manually to Xcode!! I even tried all of the conversion solutions at:

[How to convert a NSData to pdf in iPhone sdk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8005726/how-to-convert-a-nsdata-to-pdf-in-iphone-sdk)

...and none work!

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: So, what is actually in `dataFile` in the first case?  Apparently not valid PDF data.

Comment: Use the debugger to step through and see where the failure is. Maybe the first line fails (it never finds the file). Maybe the dictionary fails (it never finds anything under those keys). And so on. This might not have anything to do with saving the NSData; the failure can happen long before we get to that point.

Comment: (Note that if the original NSData object is a PDF image then no "conversion" to PDF should be required.  All you're trying to do is write the file.)

Comment: @HotLicks thanks for the clarification (no conversion is needed), furthermore error solved, there was a bug in the saving process of the NSData itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is not in these lines of code. Your issue is that either:

- the downloaded file is corrupt (so your information in the NSData is corrupt)
- `ReaderDocument`, the class you use to open the file, has an bug and downloads the file incorrectly

Maybe the PDF file uses some PDF features which are not supported by your `ReaderDocument` class? PDF is a very broad format.